# how to empty an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with list of objects. By clicking remove all item button, that array will be empty. But, action event is not working for that button and items are still there.

I have tried to listlength to 0 but it is not working. Here is my code

component code:

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
               open:false,
               configuredList:[]
        };
       this.configLocation = this.configLocation.bind(this);
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.removeConfigLocation = this.removeConfigLocation.bind(this);
        this.removeLocationAll = this.removeLocationAll.bind(this);
        this.handleChecklocation = this.handleChecklocation.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedAdded = this.handleCheckedAdded.bind(this);
    }

    togglePanel (e){
        this.setState({open : !this.state.open});
    }

//other action code


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if(this.props.locationData !=null && this.props.locationData!= undefined){
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
      }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || prevProps.locationData != this.props.locationData)){ 
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
    }

    configLocation(locationData){
        let configuredList =[];
        if(locationData.locations.locationDetails != null && locationData.locations.locationDetails !=undefined ){
            locationData.locations.locationDetails.map(item=>{
                 let listitem ={...item};
                 configuredList.push(listitem);
            });
        }
        this.setState({configuredList},()=>{
            console.log(this.state.configuredList);
        }); 
    }

    removeLocationAll(){
        this.state.configuredList.length = 0;
    }

    removeConfigLocation(index){
        this.setState({
            configuredList:this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails.filter((_,i)=>i!==index)
        },()=>{
            console.log(this.state.configuredList);
        });

    }


    //other codes

    render(){
        //const{configuredList} = this.state;
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)}>
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                     <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                     </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                        <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.state.configuredList.map((loc,index)=><span key={index}>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}{index < this.state.configuredList.length-1 ?',\u00A0' : ''}</span>)}
                           <span onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                   </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
              {this.state.open?(
                        <div className="panel-body">
                             <div className="row grid-divider">
                                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                                  <div className="col-padding">
                                  <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="submitSmallBtn2">Delete Checked</button><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>this.removeLocationAll()}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
              <div><table className="table"><thead>{this.state.configuredList.map((locc,index)=><tr key={index}><th><input type="checkbox"/><label></label></th><th className="text-left"><b>{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</b></th><th className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>{this.removeConfigLocation(index)}} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></th></tr>)}</thead><tbody>
                        {this.props.conLocations.map((loct,index)=><tr key={index}>
                           <td><input type="checkbox"/><label></label></td>
                           <td><b>{loct.mruCode} - {_labels[loct.division]} - {loct.country}</b></td>
                           <td className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>this.handleRemove(loct.mruCode)}className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody></table></div>

                                   </div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div> 
                    </div>):null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations:state.locationRed.conLocations,
        isChecked:state.locationRed.isChecked
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(addLocation(mruCode))},
        addAllLocation:() =>{dispatch(addAllLocation())},
        removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
        removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())},
        checkboxState:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(checkboxState(mruCode))},
        checkedLocation:()=>{dispatch(checkedLocation())}
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps,null,{withRef:true})(NewLocationPanel);
```

So, i am not able to understand why this 'removeLocatonAll()' event is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While removing items, you need to setState with configuredList to empty so that a re-render is called and the change is reflected instead of directly mutating the state

```
removeLocationAll(){
    this.setState({configuredList: []});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
removeLocationAll(){
     this.setState({configuredList:[]});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the function `removeLocationAll`, you are mutating state directly which is wrong. If you want to change the state, you must use setState method only.

```
removeLocationAll(){
  this.setState({configuredList:[]});
}
```

This is the proper way to handle the state. Never try to mutate the state directly, else React will not be able to find the state change in your code.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you should never update the state object like that!
you should always use `this.setState({...})`

Coming to your answer, You need to use `this.setState({configuredList: []})`;